# SocketServer ThreadingTCPServer & Asyncore Dispatcher

Tags: python, sockets, asyncsocket, socketserver, asyncore

I want to add a timeout to individual connections within my request handler for a server using the SocketServer module.

Let me start by saying this is the first time I'm attempting to do network programming using Python. I've sub-classed SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler and SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer & SocketServer.TCPServer and managed to create two classes with some basic threaded TCP functionality.

However I would like my incoming connections to time-out. Trying to override any of the built in SocketServer time-out values and methods does not work, as the documentation says this works only with forking server. I have managed to create a timer thread that fires after X seconds, but due to the nature of the blocking recv call within the Handler thread, this is of no use, as I would be forced to kill it, and this is something I really want to avoid.

So it is my understanding that I need an asyncore implementation, where I get notified and read certain amount of data. In the event that no data is sent over a period of 5 seconds lets say, I want to close that connection (I know how to cleanly do that).
I have found a few examples of using asyncore with sockets, but none using SocketServer. So, how can I implement asyncore & threadingTCPserver ? 
Is it possible? 
Has anyone done it?

Comment: You *can* do things this way, but I recommend exploring an easier and more powerful approach - http://twistedmatrix.com/ - and welcome to the world of Python network programming! :)

Comment: Jean-Paul Calderone thank you for the link. I've seen it before. And in normal circumstances i would opt for twistedmatrix, but this is a project for a client who is very security-conscious and does not want opensource or 3rd party libraries.

Comment: That's very sad and the logic is invalid (Python is open source and third party).  Good luck on your project, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also set a timeout on the `recv` call, like this:

```
sock.settimeout(1.0)
```

Since you use `SocketServer`, you will have to find the underlying `socket` somewhere in the `SocketServer`. Please note that `SocketServer` will create the socket for you, so there is no need to do that yourself.

You will probably have defined a `RequestHandler` to go with your `SocketServer`. It should look something like this:

```
class RequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
    def setup(self):
         # the socket is called request in the request handler
         self.request.settimeout(1.0)

    def handle(self):
         while True:
             try: 
                 data = self.request.recv(1024)
                 if not data:
                      break # connection is closed
                 else:
                      pass  # do your thing
             except socket.timeout:
                 pass # handle timeout
```

Comment: I cannot get this to work sadly. I've tried (within the request handler) to do:
sock = self.server.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock = self.request.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Every time I do this, the connection just fails

Comment: Thank you so much ! this is working with ForkingTCPServer, does exactly what I wanted. Will test it with ThreadingTCPServer and see if it works there too. Again, thank you !!!